# Magento perfomance through moving htacces to virtualhost httpd

Tags: performance

we are in the process of moving the contents of htaccess to vitrualhost

What are the speed improvements others have seen?

And am I missing (security related) directives

I am currently no to impressed with the improvements on http://gtmetrix.com/

**[Below our config for future reference]**

Use within httpd.conf or the directadmin specific httpd.conf for your domain

Within  directive

```
######################################################
################## MAGENTO CONFIG ####################
######################################################

<Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html">

AllowOverride None

############################################
## default index file

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

php_flag session.auto_start off

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>

############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

AddDefaultCharset Off
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

############################################
## By default allow all access

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

############################################
## SPEED SPEED SPEED SPEED SPEED SPEED SPEED
## SETTINGS SETTINGS SETTINGS SETTINGS SETTINGS 
############################################

############################################
## http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/allowed_memory_size_exhausted  
## Increase memory limit according to Magento
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## enable resulting html compression of php output
php_flag zlib.output_compression on

############################################
## enable apache served files compression (not php, html/images/css/js
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Insert filter on all content
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Insert filter on selected content types only
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>

############################################
## Enable keep-alives to reduce # http requests
## http://yoast.com/magento-performance-hosting/

#KeepAlive On
#KeepAliveTimeout 2

## <ifModule mod_headers.c>
## Header set Connection keep-alive
## </ifModule>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 14 days"
</IfModule>

</Directory>

<Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/app">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/errors">
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|phtml)$">
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

</Directory>

<Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/pkginfo">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all 
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/lib">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all 
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/var">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all 
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/includes">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all 
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/media">
Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

php_flag engine 0

</IfModule>

AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
############################################
## enable rewrites
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
############################################
## never rewrite for existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php
RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
</IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/media/customer">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all 
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/media/downloadable">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all 
</Directory>

<Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/downloader">
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    RemoveOutputFilter DEFLATE 
    RemoveOutputFilter GZIP
</IfModule>

<Files ~ "\.(cfg|ini|xml)$">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files> 

</Directory>

<Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/downloader/template">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all 
</Directory>

######################################################
######################################################
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin Shroeder has some benchmarking about using htaccess vs httpd on his blog:

http://www.eschrade.com/page/why-you-should-not-use-htaccess-allowoverride-all-in-production/

There are gains to be realized - but I want to set your expectation - there is **no magic bullet** for performance. If you're looking to double your transactions-per-second metric, moving htaccess to httpd.conf **isn't going to do it**. However, [using opcode cache (APC), a fast backend cache](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/speeding-up-magento-with-apc-or-memcached/) (memcached [or my preference - redis](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis)), [tuning your Apache](http://www.nexcess.net/magento-best-practices-whitepaper) setup, [tuning MySQL](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/mysql-and-magento-peformance-tuning/), load balancing - these can all increase throughput and speed up the end user experience. What I'm trying to point out is dramatic performance gains are only realized cumulatively.

**Rewrite your htaccess**

Back to your original question - there are converter tools available. One such converter (written in PHP) is linked below and the output of your converted .htaccess is below that.

While I'm not sure that this actually works perfectly (I don't use Apache) it seems fairly legit.

https://github.com/preinheimer/htaccessConverter

Your htaccess rewritten:

```
<Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html">

    AllowOverride None

    ############################################
    ## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>

    ############################################
    ## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

    ############################################
    ## disable automatic session start
    ## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

    ###########################################
    # disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

    ###########################################
    # turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_security.c>
    ###########################################
    # disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>

    ############################################
    ## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    ############################################
    ## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    ############################################
    ## workaround for HTTP authorization
    ## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    ############################################
    ## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

    ############################################
    ## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    ############################################
    ## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

    </IfModule>

    ############################################
    ## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
    ## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    ############################################
    ## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    ###########################################
    ## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

    ############################################
    ## SPEED SPEED SPEED SPEED SPEED SPEED SPEED
    ## SETTINGS SETTINGS SETTINGS SETTINGS SETTINGS 
    ############################################

    ############################################
    ## http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/allowed_memory_size_exhausted  
    ## Increase memory limit according to Magento
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

    ############################################
    ## enable resulting html compression of php output
    php_flag zlib.output_compression on

    ############################################
    ## enable apache served files compression (not php, html/images/css/js
    ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Insert filter on all content
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>

    ############################################
    ## Enable keep-alives to reduce # http requests
    ## http://yoast.com/magento-performance-hosting/

    #KeepAlive On
    #KeepAliveTimeout 2

    ## <ifModule mod_headers.c>
    ## Header set Connection keep-alive
    ## </ifModule>

    ############################################
    ## Add default Expires header
    ## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 14 days"
    </IfModule>

    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/app">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/errors">
    <FilesMatch "\.(xml|phtml)$">
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>

    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/pkginfo">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all 
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/lib">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all 
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/var">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all 
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/includes">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all 
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/media">
    Options All -Indexes

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>

    php_flag engine 0

    </IfModule>

    AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
    Options -ExecCGI

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ############################################
    ## enable rewrites
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    ############################################
    ## never rewrite for existing files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    ############################################
    ## rewrite everything else to index.php
    RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/media/customer">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all 
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/media/downloadable">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all 
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/downloader">
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        RemoveOutputFilter DEFLATE 
        RemoveOutputFilter GZIP
    </IfModule>

    <Files ~ "\.(cfg|ini|xml)$">
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files> 

    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/admin/domains/domain.com/public_html/downloader/template">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all 
</Directory>
```